# A Proof of Banach-Steinhaus Theorem in Big Rudin

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading Theorem 5.8 in Rudin's RCA. It is the Banach-Steinhaus theorem. The attached image contains the claim and proof.
[image]
In the proof, Rudin says that since 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha x||\leq 2N$$
for all $||x||\leq r$, 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha||\leq 2N/r$$
holds.
Note that Rudin defined 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha||=\sup{||\Lambda_\alpha x||: x\in X, ||x||\leq 1}.$$

I don't understand the Rudin says that since 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha x||\leq 2N$$
for all $||x||\leq r$, 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha||\leq 2N/r$$
holds. How did Rudin show the inequality $||\Lambda_\alpha||\leq 2N/r$?

My attempts:
Since $||x||\leq r$, there is some $m$ such that $x=my$, with $||y||=1, 0<m\leq r$ (actually, $||x||=m||y||\leq r$). Then 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha x||=||\Lambda_\alpha (my)||=m||\Lambda_\alpha y||\leq 2N$$ for some $y$
I want to see that 
$$||\Lambda_\alpha||=\sup ||\Lambda_\alpha y||\leq 2N/m$$
but the equality $||\Lambda_\alpha x||=||\Lambda_\alpha (my)||=m||\Lambda_\alpha y||\leq 2N$ holds only some $y$.  How to justify it? Is my way wrong?

Answer (score 4):

We have to show that for all $x\in X$ such that $\lVert x\rVert\leq 1$, $\lVert \Lambda_a x\rVert\leq 2N/r$. Let $x$ be such that $\lVert x\rVert\leq 1$. Then   $\lVert rx\rVert\leq r$ hence $\lVert \Lambda_a (rx)\rVert\leq 2N$. Since $\lVert \Lambda_a (rx)\rVert=r\lVert \Lambda_a x\rVert$, we derive what we wanted.